# Generate link to a file uploaded on server to share

Tags: python, html, web-applications

I am working on a ftp application. I have a page which contains list of files uploaded. I want to create a generate link button or a read only text field that contains download link to that file for other users. So when someone goes to the link file starts downloading and download page (its just a simple html page with your file is being downloaded) is rendered.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: I feel like this would strongly depend on which web framework you're using. Also might involve Javascript.

Comment: I am using jinja2 but I have no knowledge about javascript so I cannot use that.

Comment: The question exactly is that if I am a user I should have a download link for the file I have uploaded. I have a download button to download it for myself but for any other users I want a link.